# DOM manipulation not working in VS Code because I had installed node

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript. and reached the DOM manipulation section. But now DOM manipulation in script.js was not working. Nor is the console.log running. So i uninstalled nodeJS. but now I get this : How do I get javascript to start running, it is linked to the html with <script src. Will DOM manipulation work with node JS, how?
node : The term 'node' is
not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that
the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: AHM, maybe it's better to format your questions correctly? Anyway there is no DOM in NodeJS, NodeJS executes on the server not inside the browser where the DOM exists.

Comment: You need to run a web server and execute it in a browser if you are doing DOM stuff.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

there is no dom or window in nodejs, because there is no window to interact with in it, javascript in nodejs only means a normal terminal program like python

you need to create html file like this

##### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### script.js

```
console.log(window)


console.log(document)
```

and then you may open index.html file in a browser or download the live server in vscode and run index.html file with it (and open developer console in browser by pressing f12)

you find everything you need in https://javascript.info/

#### update

you can't see your console.log in vscode because the javascript you write will be executed inside the browser, when you open the browser you must click f12 and open the console tab to see your output, you may use alert function as an alternative